# Using Aws-RDS, getting too many db connections with only 2 app users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

[image]

using Amazon-RDS, with medium sized instance (db.t2.medium) has max connections limit of aroud 400, still get almost full db connections, even when only 2 users are using the app, using it with mobile apis only (android) not making calls from anywhere else.
What might be the issue, where are all these connections coming from ? 
DDOS ? can ddos led to this, but we bought brand new server

Comment: Connect using the mysql workbench or other utility that lets you see where the client connections are coming from. 95% of the time this is long running/hung queries or a problem with your connection pool.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably not closing connections when you're done with them.

Log into the database as the root user and execute this query:

```
select HOST, COMMAND, count(*) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST group by 1, 2;
```

It will give you output that looks like this:

```
+-----------+---------+----------+
| HOST      | COMMAND | count(*) |
+-----------+---------+----------+
| localhost | Query   |        1 |
| localhost | Sleep   |        1 |
+-----------+---------+----------+
```

If you have two users with stable IP addresses, you'll probably see four lines of output: two for each user, with a high count for `Sleep`. This indicates that you're leaving connections open.

If you're running on mobile, however, the IP addresses may not be stable. You'll need to do a second level of analysis to see if they're all from the same ISP(s).

The only way that a DDOS would fill up your connection pool is if you've leaked the database password. If that's the case, you should consider your database corrupted and start over (with more attention to security).